# Visual basic says 'There are characters in the path that are invalid' but when i display the characters at a textbox they look right

Tags: vb.net, path

```
      Dim pathvalue2 = Form1.drivelabel.Text
Problem here ->   IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathvalue2 & "server_tool_data\server_files\21")

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathvalue2 & "server_tool_data\server_files\21\server.jar", My.Resources.server.jar)
                Me.Enabled = False
                loadingForm.Show()
                Me.Enabled = True
```

Visual basic says 'There are characters in the path that are invalid' but when i display the characters in a textbox they look right.Pathvalue is a drive's letter e.g. C:\
.The path `"server_tool_data\server_files\21"` is right

Comment: What is this: `Dim pathvalue2 = Form1.drivelabel.Text`? What is `Form1`, specifically? Should it be `Me` instead? Or is that another Form's instance? If so, where does it come from?

Comment: Dim pathvalue2 = Form1.drivelabel.Text pathvalue is a a drive's letter.pathvalue equals with the text of drivelabel which contains a drive letter

Comment: Yes, well, the question was: What is `Form1`, specifically? Where does it come from? Also in relation to `Me`: what is the class name of `Me`?

Comment: the label "drivelabel comes from an another form

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and add a watch for your path expression.  You may have an illegal character that's not visible when you put it in a text box, for example a newline character.  You should also inspect `drivelabel` in debug mode too.

Comment: i put a breakpoint and it says "C:/" & CLvb or something like that

Answer (score 0):

The file path to any file in the C drive starts as follows:

```
C:\
```

not

```
C:/
```

Comment: i know that is C:\

Comment: then why don't you put it in your question